# Hibernation doesn't fully turn off computer

Tags: hibernate

Pm-hibernate succesfully writes everything in the RAM to my swap partition and turns off the harddrive yet the activity light at the front of my laptop is still on and I think I can hear the fan spinning slightly. How do I solve this? I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

Comment: does it work properly if you type "systemctl hibernate" in a terminal?

Comment: No, every hibernate option does the same (hibernate/pm-hibernate/systemctl)